# A moving element to push adjacent element only if they collide

Tags: html, css

I have a container with 2 children.

One child has dynamic width and at it's maximum width can fill the container

The other child has fixed width and starts off being hidden as it's starting point is to the right of the `overflow:hidden` container

What I want is the fixed-width child to move to the left so that it exactly fits into the right of the container such that

a) If both children fit into the container - the other element should say put on the left and

b) If there is no room for both elements - the fixed-width element should push the other element to the left as much as it needs to in order to fit into the right of the container.

Here is what I tried:

### [Attempt #1](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/epfqjtft/4/)

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: noWrap;
}
span {
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.child1 {
  background: aqua;
  float: right;
  width: 50px;
  margin-right: -50px;
  transition: margin .2s;
}
.container:hover .child1 {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.child2 {
  background: tomato;
  //width: 100%;  

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="child1">Fixed</span>
  <span class="child2">Dynamic Width</span>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span class="child1">Fixed</span>
  <span class="child2">Here is a Dynamic Width box</span>
</div>
```

Condition a) Succeeds but condition b) Fails

### [Attempt #2](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/epfqjtft/5/)

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: noWrap;
}
span {
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.child2 {
  background: aqua;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
  margin-right: -50px;
  transition: margin .2s;
}
.container:hover .child1 {
  margin-left: -50px;
}
.container:hover .child2 {
  margin: 0;
}
.child1 {
  background: tomato;
  transition: margin .2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="child1">Dynamic Width</span>
  <span class="child2">Fixed</span>
</div>

<div class="container">

  <span class="child1">Here is a Dynamic Width box</span>
  <span class="child2">Fixed</span>
</div>
```

Condition a) Fails and condition b) Succeeds

Can both conditions be fulfilled with CSS alone?

PS: The markup which I provided in the demos may be modified. Also CSS3 including flexbox is also fine.

Comment: @jbutler483 - I updated Demo2 to demonstrate what I meant - thanks.

Comment: quite difficult just using css

Comment: I didn't get it completely good but maybe this gives you some direction to your answer: http://jsfiddle.net/epfqjtft/6/ and http://jsfiddle.net/epfqjtft/7/

Comment: @LinkinTED No I want to push the dynamic width div to the left (pushing it out of the container)

Comment: @LinkinTED No need to know parent size. Check my CSS only answer.

Comment: @Danield I added a second solution without CSS3 transformations.

Comment: @NaeemShaikh Is quite difficult with just CSS, but not impossible. Pls check my answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is a CSS only solution.

The trick is to use this basic rule:
Consider two or more inline elements rendered side by side.
If you increase the width of the first element, the second elements is pushed to the right.

The problem is that you need the elements to move to the left. I solved this by inverting the X direction to the child elements `scaleX(-1)` and re-inverting again the container.
To help you better understand this, you can comment out the `transform: scaleX(-1);` in the jsfiddle link below, and watch what happens.

The beauty of this is that you don't need to know the width of the `.child2`. You just need to push it to the left.

```css
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: right;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}

span {
   height: 50px;
   display: inline-block;
   transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.child1 {
    background: aqua;
    width: 50px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    float: left;
    transition: margin-left .2s;
    text-align: left;
}

.child2 {
   background: tomato;
}

.container:hover .child1 {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span class="child1">Fixed</span>
    <span class="child2">Dynamic Width</span>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <span class="child1">Fixed</span>
    <span class="child2">Here is a Dynamic Width box</span>
</div>
```

Also on **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epfqjtft/11/)**

---

## Solution 2

Another slightly simpler solution is to use `direction: rtl;` on the container. By reversing the direction of inline elements from **r**ight **t**o **l**eft, we achieve the same effect without the need to use CSS3 transformations.
See **http://jsfiddle.net/epfqjtft/12/**

Comment: well done. I didn't even think of this sort of implementation.

Comment: Awsome solution, thumbs up!

Comment: Where can I add favorite answer?

Answer (score 7):

Since css can't do conditional statements (bar media queries), I don't think this is *truly* possible with css alone.

**update**

---

I have seen that it *is* in fact possible using CSS3 transforms (which works in modern browsers). but just in case some users might want older browser support which CSS3 transforms cant provide, i'll leave this here anyway.

---

Apart from that, I've used positioning instead of floats to 'clean up' the styling (and attempted the jquery):

```js
$('.container').hover(function() {

  var parentWidth = $(this).width();
  var thisWidth = $(this).find(".child1").width() + 50; /*i.e. width of fixed box*/
  if (parentWidth < thisWidth) { /*if it doesn't fit, move it!*/
    $(this).find('.child1').addClass("moveLeft");
  }
}, function() {
  $(this).find(".child1").removeClass("moveLeft");
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: noWrap;
  position: relative;
}
span {
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.child2 {
  background: aqua;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -50px;
  transition: all .2s;
}
.child1 {
  background: tomato;
  transition: all .2s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.container:hover .child2 {
  right: 0;
}
.moveLeft:hover {
  left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <span class="child1">Dynamic Width</span>
  <span class="child2">Fixed</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <span class="child1">Here is a Dynamic Width box</span>
  <span class="child2">Fixed</span>
</div>
```

---

As for your 'solution', you will have to test if the `child + 50px` is `greater than` the parent width, if so, move `child1`. If not, no action is needed.

Comment: Thanks for this jQuery solution, but I'm still not 100% sure that it's impossible with CSS

Comment: @Danield: I wasn't totally sure either when I first looked, but thinking now by tinkering that unfortunately I believe it is (I would *love* to be proved wrong, btw). But from the conditions, I don't think it is :(

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I changed LinkinTED's code a little bit. Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/epfqjtft/9/

Of course, I don't know if it's something you can work with. These types of problems should be solved with Jquery.

```
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid green;

    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    transition: all 2s;
}
span {
   height: 50px;
   display: table-cell;
    transition: all .2s;
}
.child1 {
    background: tomato;
    width: 100%;
}
.child2 {
    background: aqua;
    width: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all .2s;
}
.container:hover .child2 {
    width: 50px;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <span class="child1">Dynamic Width</span>
    </div>
    <span class="child2">Fixed</span>
</div>    
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <span class="child1">Here is a Dynamic Width box</span>
    </div>
    <span class="child2">Fixed</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is looking for I'm afraid.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.container {
    width: 250px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid read;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: right;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}

span {
   height: 50px;
   display: inline-block;
   transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.child1 {
    background: pink;
    width: 50px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    float: left;
    transition: margin-left .3s;
    text-align: left;
}

.child2 {
   background: #####;
}

.container:hover .child1 {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <span class="child1">Fixed</span>
    <span class="child2">Dynamic Width</span>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <span class="child1">Fixed</span>
    <span class="child2">Here is  Dynamic Width box</span>
</div>
```

Comment: please add some description explaining your answer rather than putting only code